# discriminant analysis cross validation

Tags: r, validation

I’ve just tried the code for the discriminant analysis, as given here: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/discriminant.html

If using this:

```
fit <- lda(G ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata, na.action="na.omit", CV=TRUE)
```

followed by this:

```
ct <- table(mydata$G, fit$class)
```

and  the dataset contains NAs (which mine did) the table cannot be produced as the two vectors are different lengths. The $G is the entire vector including NAs but the $class has the NAs removed, and therefore is of a different length.

Is there a way to remove the data points of the $G vector which were removed, before using the table() command?

Comment: Where in the code should na.omit be used?

Comment: Try using `na.exclude` where you have `na.omit`. Does that help? `na.exclude` puts NAs back in when making predictions, which may be useful in this circumstance.